# Can't Find Content Permissions Referenced in Official Documentation

Tags: profile, contentdistribution, system-permissions

I'm developing a solution which leverages *ContentDistribution*, and I'm figuring out access levels and permissions. I read this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) in the Soap API Developer Guide:

[image]

However, I can't find the highlighted permission in profile system permissions. Is it elsewhere or was it actually reworded to **Create Content Deliveries** as below?

[image]

Comment: a useful reference is http://www.fishofprey.com/ @DanielBallinger